# How to create 2D ImageHistogram?

Tags: plotting, image, histograms

Using ImageHistogram I can find the frequency of each color value in an image. Applying the same, I can have a histogram of its gradient values. I wish to combine these two on a log scale such that X - axis will represent the color values and Y - axis will represent the gradient values and each entry in the 2D histogram plot will represent the frequency of pixels having a specific color and gradient values.

Consider the image of Lena.

[image]

The color histogram of this is:

[image]

And the gradient histogram is:

[image]

Below is what I expect as my 2D histogram:

[image]

The problem is how to display the frequency of a pair of color and gradient values through ImageHistogram.

Edit 1: After getting suggestion from Szabolcs, I've modified the code and got result as follows:

```
im = ColorConvert[lena, "Grayscale"];
intensity = Flatten@ImageData[im];
gradient = Flatten@ImageData@GradientFilter[im, 1];
vals = Transpose[{gradient, intensity}];
plot1 = ImageHistogram[im]
```

and got the result as

[image]

```
plot2 = Rotate[ImageHistogram[GradientFilter[im, 1]], 90 Degree]
```

and the corresponding plot is:

[image]

And the joint plot is:

[image]

However, I'm not sure whether I've got the desired result. Can anyone please confirm me?

Comment: Assuming grayscale `im`, `vals = Transpose[{Flatten@ImageData@GradientFilter[im, 1], 
    Flatten@ImageData[im]}];`, then use `BinCounts` with a suitable (perhaps manually constructed) bin specification to bin the 2D data.  This should get you started.

Comment: E.g. `BinCounts[vals, {2^Range[-12, 0]}, {Range[0, 1, 0.05]}] // MatrixPlot`